# How to make a function that sorts and returns the most repeated value of array in descending order in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, function, sorting

How to make a function that sorts and returns the most repeated value of array in descending order in javascript, if my array is:

```js
const array = ["bill", "bill", "anup", "max", "bill", "max"]
```

and i want a function to return `["bill", "max", "anup"]` as `bill` is the most repeated value so its in index `0` and `max` is second repeated value so its index is `1` and anup in `2`.

is it possible to make that function? I heard doing it with nested `for loop` but i am not sure how to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const array = ["bill", "bill", "anup", "max", "bill", "max"]

console.log(x(array))


function x(list) {
  let tmp = new Map()
  array.forEach(x => {
    tmp.set(x, (tmp.get(x) || 0) + 1)
  })
  return [...tmp.entries()].sort((a, b) => {
    return a[1] < b[1] ? 1 : -1
  }).map(x=>x[0])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const array = ["bill", "bill", "anup", "max", "bill", "max"]

let result = [...new Set(array)]
.sort((a,b) => array.filter(e => b===e).length - array.filter(e => a===e).length)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const returnMost = (array) => {

  const arrayCounter = {

  }

  array.forEach(elem => {
    if (arrayCounter[elem]) {
      arrayCounter[elem]++
    } else {
      arrayCounter[elem] = 1
    }
  })

  const result = Object.keys(arrayCounter).sort((a,b) => {
    if (arrayCounter[a] > arrayCounter[b]) {
    return  -1
    } else {
      return 1
    }

  } )

  console.log(result);
  return result
}
```

Comment: For the array from the question, does this return `["bill", "max", "anup"]` as requested?

Comment: Your interpreter must be more verbose than the one I used, which just shows `"bill"`.

Comment: As that happens to all of us, just keep wary of *them*.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the array and find out repeated items.

```
var duplicate = []
const array = ["bill", "bill", "anup", "max", "bill", "max"]
  
function findDuplicate(arr){
     for(var i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) {  
            for(var j = i + 1; j < arr.Length; j++) {  
                if(arr[i] == arr[j])  
                    duplicate.push(arr[j]);  
            }  
return duplicate;
}

findDuplicate(arr);
```

Then, you could sort the array. I advice to use the Bubble Sort algorithm for begginers!

Comment: ya, ive heard about bubble sort algorithm, i will check it out, thanks'

Comment: Braces look out of balance. Is that last line to be a recursive call, or did you intend to pass `array`?